# Animation in visibility from hidden to collapsed and vice versa

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, styles

I am trying to achieve something similar to iPhone message view. On a button click, a delete button would slide out for every message and on clicking "done" the delete buttons would slide in. I have been able to achieve that using mvvm except the **sliding** effect.
Here is the style I could write with my limited knowledge:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowDeleteButton}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here "ShowDeleteButton" is a bool property in the view model. This works fine. but the collapsing and "getting visible" is happening abruptly and very fast. I need some sliding animation.
Please note that as the delete buttons disappear, the rest of the controls should take up the rest of space and, as the button appear, the existing controls should shrink and give space to the buttons.
I tried with storyboard animation but even after a couple hours I am not able to figure out the strange errors it is throwing. Here is the code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowDeleteButton}" Value="false">
     <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:1">
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visiblity">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:1">
                 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visiblity">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
      </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Can someone please help the soul in distress?

regards

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Old question... huh...

Anyway... forget about visibility. The trick is to animate `Width/Height` of the Control placed in `Grid's Column/Row` where the `Column/Row` has **Width set to Auto.** Uff :)

So here is a `Grid` named "container" with two columns. In the first column can be placed whatever you want, but you should align it to Right since you want it to move when your delete button is displayed. And in the second column there is a Control *(representing your DeleteButton)* Notice that first column has `Width="*"` and second column has `Width="Auto"`

```xml
<Grid Background="Purple" Width="350" Height="100">
    <CheckBox Content="Show" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowDeleteButton}" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Grid x:Name="container" Margin="40,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="content" Margin="0">
            <Label Content="Look I'm flyin'!" Margin="0,30,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
        <Control Grid.Column="1" Margin="0">
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowDeleteButton}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="flyout"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Width)" 
                                From="0" To="120" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="flyout"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Width)" 
                                From="120" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Grid x:Name="flyout" Width="0">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
                        <Label Content="I'm DELETE button" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And the `Control` in Grid's second column has `DataTrigger` based on your ViewModel's property *"ShowDeleteButton"*

Since the `Width` of column where the `Control` is placed is `Auto` you can change the width of the `Control` using simple `DoubleAnimation` and you get desired behavior.

**EDIT**

Look at this if you want the flyout to be over everything else.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="container" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="In" Margin="0,13,7.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="flyout"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Width)" 
                                    From="0" To="120" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/> 
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="flyout" Width="120" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
            <Label Content="This is some label" Margin="6.038,27,1.006,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button Content="Out" Margin="11.917,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80.083">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="flyout"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Width)" 
                                    From="120" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False"/> 
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Please note that button "Out" can be clicked while it's moving. It should be probably disabled. I just did it like this because I wanted to do it simple and all in xaml. Sure you can use mahapps. Or you can just make it as fast as it is in MahApps and it's impossible to click it twice. :) I have looked at MahApps FlyOutDemo and my solution looks much simpler to me. And I don't need third party library.

Comment: Thank you @Viktor! However this is not exactly what I wanted. This approach is actually re sizing my existing view to accommodate the new view. However, I wanted a flyout that would come over the existing view. MahApps metro offers one such control. :) I appreciate your effort to answer the old question though! Cheers..

Comment: @James then what this means? "as the button appear, the existing controls should shrink and give space to the buttons." If you don't want that then still approach could be the same... animate width in grid with auto width. If you can't manage that I can look at it one more time. i have tried MahApps.Metro... don't like it. :)

Comment: Hi @Viktor thanks again I will be trying this. btw do you mind letting me know what makes you dislike MahApps? One thing is for sure from my side, they dont provide styles for datagrid and datepicker. What are the reasons from your side?

Comment: Works Like a charm!Had solved it much earlier though, from the tutorial here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kkr4DtVOYmI
However, I appreciate the effort you took to answer the question. Cheers Viktor!

Comment: Excellent explanation thanks!