# WPF MVVM - Info bar sliding animation

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, styles

I'm very new to the animation / graphical side of WPF and struggling.

I have a user control which consists of 4 text boxes and a button.

I am looking to have a bar slide down from the top of the control and display datatemplates

I don't have a any code or examples to add which I have written so far really as my angles of attack have been so varied. I am under the understanding that I want a Storyboard for Expand and Collapse but not sure how to animate this from a MVVM perspective.

Would it be best to use a DockPanel or Stackpanel with a content control in maybe? Or something totally different?

Any relevant animation or mvvm/animation tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Edit - Added "rough" concept image.

[image]

Thanks.
Steve

Comment: If you don't post any XAML, at least post a screenshot of what you need, so that we may have an idea what it's like. If not here in Stackoverflow, try `imgur.com` and then link the image in the question.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10701898/1456174) is question about animation from hidden to collapsed and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created 2 properties in the view model.
ShowPane - boolean
PaneInfo - Class bound to a content control to show a DataTable displaying the relevant info.

```
<Control>
     <Control.Template>
           <ControlTemplate>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowPane}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InfoPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)" From="0" To="50" Duration="0:0:.5" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InfoPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)" From="50" To="0" Duration="0:0:.5" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding PaneInfo}" Name="InfoPanel" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
```